# How to get the PDF export log by Presentation ID with Google Activity API

Tags: google-apps-activity

I'm beginner the Google Activity API but I have experience GAS or other API(SpreadSheet API, Presentation API ). I want to know the export time of PDF from Presentation ID. Is it possible by using this API?

Comment: Can I ask you about the method for exporting the Google Slides?

Comment: @Tanaike

I found it. 
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/activities/list

In this API, the response included the download name by specifying the Presentation ID. 

□request 
https://gyazo.com/d2c0cee45b3488b96cab96a497645ca9

□rsponse 
'''
   "events": [
    {
     "type": "access",
     "name": "download",
     "parameters": [
'''

Comment: I apologize I couldn't help.